Movie where three people get locked in a hotel
It was a movie, I believe was on Netflix, and I only remember certain parts. There was a couple, and the girlfriend's friend and the couple drove to this hotel. They ended up getting locked in the hotel. I don't know if it was spirits locking them in, but anyway the food started going bad and there was one scene where the boyfriend tried eating maggot-covered chicken and he ends up throwing up. Another scene is when the boyfriend ties up his girlfriend and tries eating her underwear? The friend and girlfriend kill him accidentally but they eat part of him and the scene was both of them blankly staring while eating part of his arm. They were at the table and one of them had cooked it. The ending scene was the friend walking out of the hotel.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  How confident are you that there are actual supernatural elements in this movie, as opposed to a movie like Saw?

thank you! i don’t think it was anything like saw because they were the only people in the hotel. i just remember they tried opening the door multiple different ways even trying to kick it down but it didn’t budge. but when the friend was the only one alive she was able to leave.

In roughly which year did you watch this?

the movie, The Exterminating Angel, also has this idea.

This is The Snare (2017).

Three friends head to the seafront for a drunken weekend, only to be imprisoned on the top floor of their holiday apartment by a malevolent paranormal force.

This is apparently an independent British film, set somewhere in England.
The protagonist is a woman named Alice, who I'd guess is supposed to be in her late twenties. She's picked up by her friend, Lizzy, and Lizzy's boyfriend, Carl, who drive her to a vacant apartment building by the sea for a drunken weekend. They haven't told anyone else where they're going and don't have permission to be there; Lizzy stole the keys from her estate agent father.
When they get there, they ride the elevator to the top floor and enter the apartment they plan to stay in, then visit a local shop to buy some groceries. The first night goes by without any problems, but the next day, they find the elevator is no longer working and the door to the stairwell is locked. Their phones aren't working either and no one responds to their cries for help from the balcony of the apartment, leaving them trapped on the top floor. Most of what little food they have starts to go bad and the faucets eventually stop working too.
About an hour into the film -- at which point they've been trapped on the top floor for over a week -- Carl gets so hungry that he eats part of a chicken leg crawling with maggots after removing some with his fingers. The film cuts from that to him throwing up in the apartment's toilet.


The Snare (2017)

He later finds Lizzy asleep on the living room floor, binds her wrists with his vest, and begins to rape her. Alice comes into the room to stop him and he tries to rape her. Then Lizzy loops a TV cable around his throat from behind and the two women strangle him to death.
After that, Alice grabs a knife and starts carving strips of flesh from one of his thighs, which she cooks and eats. Lizzy looks on silently as she does this.
I'm skipping over some plot to avoid spoilers that weren't mentioned in the question, but the film ends with Alice walking (hobbling) out of the building.
The paranormal aspect of the film is implicit rather than explicit, and open to interpretation. Alice has frightening visions and nightmares and senses an unseen presence, which she believes is what was keeping them in the building. She also finds writing etched into her bedroom wall beneath the wallpaper, suggesting that others had previously been trapped in the building. I suspect the filmmakers drew inspiration from Kubrick's The Shining in some respects, although this film doesn't begin to measure up to that classic.




"A charming romp that all the family can enjoy" ~ Empire Magazine.

"If I had a nickel for every film about three people being trapped in a hotel by mystical forces and being forced into eating moldy food, and then cannibalism, I'd have two nickels. Which isn't a lot, but it's weird that it's happened twice."

@FuzzyBoots - There are no new stories. Both are actually based on Emma by Jane Austen.

@FuzzyBoots I read that Doofenshmirtz's voice...

@Wondercricket: ^_^ I almost included the meme, but couldn't get the link to work.

Could this be Portal (2009)?
A couple and their friend gets
stuck in a mysterious and horrific hotel and are forced to eat unpalatable food including raw meat with maggots.

Soon after finding shelter in the mysterious, fog engulfed town of Mercy, two friends plan to rest up for their next day's journey only to realize, as nights turn to nights, that time is not only on their side - time doesn't exist.




